# SFML Socket Being set to sf::Socket::Error when sending a packet

Tags: c++, networking, udp, sfml

I am attempting to use UDP and packets to create a networking framework for game development.  I am able to recieve packets sent from the client to the server, but when the server tries to send a packet in response to the packet it receives, it the socket's state is set to Error and does not send the packet.  Here is the affected server code:

The server .cpp file:

```
#include "ServerCore.hpp"
#include "Packet.hpp"

#include <SFML/Network/IpAddress.hpp>
#include <iostream>

ServerCore::ServerCore(int port)
    : mSocketRecv()
    , mSocketSend()
{
    mPort = port;
}

void ServerCore::enterServerLoop()
{
    if(mSocketRecv.bind(mPort) != sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        std::cout << "SOMETHING DIDNT WORK" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Initialized Server" << std::endl;

    unsigned short port;
    sf::IpAddress ip;
    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << ":D" << std::endl;

        sf::Packet packet;

        std::size_t recieved;

        if(mSocketRecv.receive(packet, ip, port) != sf::Socket::Done)
        {

        }

        int x;

        if(packet >> x)
        {
            if(x == ClientPacket::PlayerConnect)
            {
                std::cout << "Player Connected!" << std::endl;
                sf::Packet packet;

                packet << ServerPacket::ServerStop;

                if(mSocketSend.send(packet, mSender, 54000) != sf::Socket::Done)
                {
                    std::cout << "I AM SAD" << std::endl;
                }
            }
            if(x == ClientPacket::PlayerDisconnect)
                std::cout << "Player Disconnected!" << std::endl;
            if(x == ClientPacket::PlayerQuit)
                std::cout << "Player Quit!" << std::endl;
            if(x == ClientPacket::PlayerJoin)
                std::cout << "Player Join!" << std::endl;

        }


        std::cout << "Recieved " << recieved << " bytes from " << ip << " on port " << port << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And the server .hpp file:

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Network/UdpSocket.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network/IpAddress.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network/Packet.hpp>

class ServerCore
{
public:
    ServerCore(int port);
    void enterServerLoop();

private:
    sf::UdpSocket mSocketRecv;
    sf::UdpSocket mSocketSend;

    sf::IpAddress mSender;
    int mPort;
};
```

This is the affected block of code (specifically the location that's not working as expected):

```
        if(x == ClientPacket::PlayerConnect)
        {
            std::cout << "Player Connected!" << std::endl;
            sf::Packet packet;

            packet << ServerPacket::ServerStop;

            if(mSocketSend.send(packet, mSender, 54000) != sf::Socket::Done)
            {
                std::cout << "I AM SAD" << std::endl;
            }
        }
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What is x, and why is it uninitialized?

Comment: X is an integer that is initialized in the if(packet >> x) statement.

Comment: Any ideas?  I cannot seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that packet is greater than UdpSocket::MaxDatagramSize ([see this](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.1-fr/classsf_1_1UdpSocket.php#a48969a62c80d40fd74293a740798e435)), you can use [getDataSize()](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.1-fr/classsf_1_1Packet.php#a004b62aa5bafa69df8917171a3fe1fa0) to check it.